# How to infer a height map from an image of an uneven surface (shape from shading)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a computer vision application that needs to infer the texture of a surface from a photo taken under illumination from a known direction. Take this embossed paper for example:

[image: embossed paper]

The brain makes various assumptions, such as that illumination comes from above and that the surface is contiguous, and arrives at a model of texture such that you can imagine what it would be like to run your finger over this surface.

This problem is called "shape from shading", is recognised to be very hard in the general case, is an active topic of research and even has [its own book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/shape-shading).

My questions is: for the specific case of a mostly flat surface with bumps in it such as embossed paper or a white-painted wall, are there any algorithms for doing this that are either released in an open source library, or simple enough that they can be assembled from primitives that are available in open source libraries like OpenCV or SciPy without requiring degree level maths?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but is [25 lines of C source code](http://vision.eecs.ucf.edu/shadsrc.html) small enough to understand?

Comment: Yes! Certainly looks like it could do the trick anyway. Old papers are always the best for simplicity.